# Is it possible to use the Vertex Array Objects ES extension from Android, using GL ES 2?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to use the Vertex Array Objects ES extension from Android, using GL ES 2?

I would expect to find VAO functions in a class named `GLES20Ext`, just as I can find ES 1 extensions in `GLES10Ext`, but I can't.

Is it possible to use VAOs from Android's Java GL ES 2 binding?

If it is not, would the easiest way to use VAOs from GLES2 be to use the NDK to bridge the extension calls? Does such a binding exist already?

Is it feasible to require ES 3, or ES 3 support not yet widely available?

Comment: In theory, this should be doable from the NDK (given Android API level 9 - 2.3+). The problem is that the actual Java bindings for EGL suck, to put it lightly - they hide `eglGetProcAddress (...)` which is necessary to expose any vendor extensions or anything that the Android GLES2.0 bindings happened to leave out (which is a lot). What you'd need to do is look for `GL_OES_vertex_array_object` in the list of supported extensions, then use the NDK to get the procedure address... you might be able to make it callable from Java, doing this.

Comment: Simply returning a function pointer to Java code doesn't get you very far -- you still need to marshal arguments, throw exceptions, and do all the other stuff that the (auto-generated) function wrappers do.  Generating bytecode on the fly is an option, but it isn't straightforward on Android.  Supporting arbitrary extensions is easier (and probably more efficient) with an NDK component.  (If you know a clever way to do it, high-quality patches are always welcome in AOSP.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no GLES20Ext.java.  This was probably an oversight.

You will need to create your own Java bindings through the NDK.

GLES 3.0 is relatively new, and not yet available on the majority of devices.  The current recommendation is to target 2.0, and do a runtime check to take advantage of 3.0 features [when they are available](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#version-check).